# Get full stack trace from exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm developing a .NET Core 2.1 application, and I need to log the exception details with my custom method. When I get stack trace into a variable it is not getting full details but I can see enough details through the text visualizer visual studio.

Below is the example:

```
at System.Number.StringToNumber(ReadOnlySpan`1 str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
   at APSM.BLL.BusinessObjects.ManageSpecification.ManageDashboard.<GetPendingInspectionListAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in D:\Mehaboob\Works\AutoPSM\APSM.BLL\BusinessObjects\ManageSpecification\ManageDashboard.cs:line 138
```

And in the variable:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(ReadOnlySpan`1 str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
   at APSM.BLL.BusinessObjects.ManageSpecification.ManageDashboard.GetPendingInspectionListAsync(DashboardVM dashboardVM)
```

You can see in the variable there is no line number and missing something.
What is the way to get a full stack trace?

Comment: You need to deploy the appropriate PDBs.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you give an example, thanks in advance

Comment: No. Just search ".NET log stack trace PDB". It will explain your problem.

Comment: Yes, @JonasH I'm looking into this.